Scan Columns for Conditions then Return Average Value of another Column
I am trying to attain the average value of the data within Column #3 but only those that fit certain conditions set by Columns #1 & #2.
For Example:
I want the average values of the data in column 3 that is a Dog and Real.



Column 1
Column 2
Column 3




Dog
Real
1


Dog
Fake
0


Cat
Fake
1


Cat
Real
0


Dog
Fake
1


Cat
Real
0



I have tried IF and AND functions but it returns FALSE as it scans the whole column to match rather than treating each row individually before going to the next.
I read also about AVERAGEIF but I ran into the same problem. I will keep trying things while I wait thank you in advance to those that respond.

For your table, the formula =AVERAGEIFS(C2:C7;A2:A7;"Dog";B2:B7;"Real") will return 1, the formula =AVERAGEIFS(C2:C7;A2:A7;"Cat";B2:B7;"Real") will return 0. Is this the result you were expecting? Then look at the description of the AVERAGEIFS() function.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works and read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help], especially what kind of questions you can ask here. I'm missing the relation to programming. Why do you think your spreadsheet formula is related? You might rather ask this on other SE sites.

@JohnSUN yes that was the answer I was expecting thank you.
